# Check if string A occurs in the end of string B

Tags: c, string, function

As part of an exercise to learn about pointer I tried to create a function
that will find if the string `t` is in the end of string `s`, and return 1 on true and 0 on false.
But it seems that I get 0 even when the condition should be right.

Here is my code:

```
int strend(char *s, char *t)
{
    int flag = 0;
    if (!s || !t)
        return 0;
    while(*s)
    {
        if (*s==*t){
            s++;
            t++;
            flag = 1;
        }
        else{
            flag = 0;
            s++;
        }
    }
    if (!*t) return flag;
    else return 0;
}
int main()
{
    char first[15] = "first";
    char second[] ="t";
    printf("strend : %d", strend(first,second));
    return 0;
}
```

I don't see where I mess this up.

Comment: As a side note, don't call your function that. Function names that begin with `str` are reserved.

Comment: Returns 1 (as expected) for me

Comment: Returns 1 to me for your inputs. You can change your while loop to while(*s && *t)

Comment: Works for `first/t` (1), `first/st` (1), `first/ts` (0). I fail to see the problem.

Comment: Its seem to work now after I quit and start the program again.
Meby its was a catch or something....thanks everyone for your time :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a quick function for you, with less lines of code. Thats my idea, if you like it, you can use it. My aim was to make that with less code as possible. Actually consider this 1 line of code.

```
int strchk (char *str1, char *str2)
{
    if(!strcmp(&str1[strlen(str1) - strlen(str2)], str2)) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow this is really nice. But why &str1 and not *str1?

Comment: Because `*str1` wouldn't make sense. You see.. `&` means "address of" and when opening index operator `[` i point a block of memory from the string's nm.

Comment: Ok, so strcmp take the address + offset(str1-str2) and compare it to str 2, then return 0 if its compare?
then you reverse i, cool

Comment: Lets get the following string: `char* str = "I love apples"`
`&str[4]` will return "ve apples"
..We return the block of memory str[4] in the string, so it kind of.. breaks it. Thats the easiest way i understood it, when i was still in process of learning.

Comment: No problem @Or Halimi